# \sin and \cos using CM font instead of chosen with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I use `STIX 2` fonts with `unicode-math`, but the names of operators are typeset with CM:

[image]

How can I fix it?

MWE (I use LuaLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIXTwo-Math}

\begin{document}

    \[
        \sin x
    \]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's expected, because the operators are typeset with the main document font, which is Latin Modern, if you don't set it otherwise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

    \[
        \sin x
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can set the font used by `\mathrm` independently of the main text font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\setmathrm{STIX Two Text}

\begin{document}

Text sin and math $\sin$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is true but I am not sure that it should be true

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Make a feature request 

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The interface is already there. All it takes is reading the manuals of `unicode-math` and `fontspec`. I know, I know. 

Answer (score 6):

er well this works but can't be the documented interface, perhaps open an issue in the unicode-math github

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS-Math}
\showoutput
\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zzz\iftrue\expandafter{\else}\fi}
\def\zzz#1{\symrm{#1}\iffalse{\else}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \[
        \sin x
    \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s a neat trick!

Comment: @WillRobertson as I mentioned under egreg's answer I suspect an option to use a math rather than text font here would be good (also a non-argument form of `\symbzz` that could be dropped in place of `\operator@font` to save abusing brace groups as above.

Comment: @WillRobertson I too think that mathrm is not the correct default operator font, it should be \symup. And perhaps this is a use case for the switch version I suggested in https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/459#issuecomment-384900248.

Comment: I don’t agree with that default. \mathrm will be kerned for multiple letters, \symup not (in the common Unicode math fonts).

Comment: @WillRobertson true and egreg claims you have a manual that says how to reset `\operator@font` so if he's to be believed then i think it's all good.

Comment: Yes I think the command is \setoperatorfont\symup or similar :-)